# Regex to filter, then determine latest date

Tags: r, regex

Say I have a directory with four files:

```
someText.abcd.xyz.10Sep16.csv 
someText.xyz.10Sep16.csv
someText.abcd.xyz.23Oct16.csv 
someText.xyz.23Oct16.csv
```

This is how the names are formatted.  I cannot change them, and the format will remain the same except the dates will change.  All of the names begin with `someText`.  Next, there is either a four-letter code (`abcd`) or a three latter code (`xyz`).  If the file name has a four letter code, it will always have a three-letter code after it.  Finally there is a date value.

I have two tasks.  First, I need to filter out the files that have the "abcd" component.  This will always be a four-character code that appears after the `someText.` in the name.  Is there a way to right a regex expression to remove these values?

That leaves two files:

```
someText.xyz.10Sep16.csv
someText.xyz.23Oct16.csv
```

I need only the file with the later date.  Is there a second regex I could do to extract the dates, find the latest, and then keep only that date?  I'm doing this to get the file set down to four:

```
myDir <- "\\\\myDir\\folder\\"
files <- list.files(path = myDir, pattern = "\\.csv$")
```

Here's a vector with the file names if someone wants to try it out:

```
files <- c("someText.abcd.xyz.10Sep16.csv", "someText.xyz.10Sep16.csv", "someText.abcd.xyz.23Oct16.csv", "someText.xyz.23Oct16.csv")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my attempt at a simple base R answer

```
# regex subset 
files <- files[!grepl("^.*?\\.[[:alpha:]]{4}\\.", files)]

# get date
dates <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(files, "\\."), "[[", 3))

files[which.max(as.Date(dates, format = "%d%b%y"))]
# [1] "someText.xyz.23Oct16.csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be robust enough to work reliably. I used `dplyr` to pass the results through and manipulate them, and `lubridate` for a convenient date extraction (`dmy`). Almost forgot: you need to load `magrittr` to get the `%$%` pipe.

I split the file names by the "."s, then slide over the results if they are missing the four-letter code section. Bind them into a data.frame for easy filtering etc. Here, filter for those missing the four-letter section, then select the one with the latest date.

```
strsplit(files, "\\.") %>%
  setNames(files) %>%
  lapply(function(x){
    if(length(x) == 4){
      x[3:5] <- x[2:4]
      x[2] <- "noCode"
    }
    rbind(x) %>%
      as.data.frame()
  }) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "fileName") %>%
  mutate(date = dmy(V4)) %>%
  filter(V2 == "noCode") %$%
  c(fileName[which.max(date)])
```

returns: "someText.xyz.23Oct16.csv"

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that this can be made more compact, but here is a base R answer:

```
# file names
file_names =c(
  "someText.abcd.xyz.10Sep16.csv",
  "someText.xyz.10Sep16.csv",
  "someText.abcd.xyz.23Oct16.csv",
  "someText.xyz.23Oct16.csv"
)

# the pattern to be tested
reg_file_names = regexec(
  pattern = "^someText\\.[a-z]{4}\\.[a-z]{3}\\.(.*).csv$",
  file_names
)

# parse out the matched dates, and look for the maximum
file_names[
  which.max(
    sapply(
      regmatches(
        x = file_names, m = reg_file_names
      ),
      function(match) {
        as.Date(
          ifelse(
            length(match) == 0,
            NA,
            match[2]
          ),
          format = "%d%b%y"
        )
      }
    )
  )
  ]
```

The regular expression that you need is fairly straightforward, and the rest of the code is just to handle the cases where there is no match, and to format the dates so that they can be compared.